# Grails: Added methods during runtime available in tests?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, metaclass

I am trying to test a controller which, in particular, is using java.io.File and some of the methods/attributes injected by Grails during runtime, like:

empty
fileItem
transferTo()

I receive the following error:

```
No such property: empty for class: java.io.File
```

Some methods are easily implemented:

```
def testFile = new File('test/unit/resources/TestScript.groovy')
File.metaClass.getFileItem = { -> testFile }
File.metaClass.isEmpty = { -> false }
```

But others are not, so I wonder if there's a way to let Grails add them for me?  My understanding was that this is done in integration tests but moving the test there gives me the same error.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Jonas

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  Those methods on `File` come from Groovy, and are part of the [Groovy JDK](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/) runtime.  They should be present as long as you are running Groovy code.  Have you tried running `grails clean`?

Comment: Where are you finding this File.empty property? I didn't see it in the GDK javadocs.

Comment: True, I cannot find it in the javadocs either. Our action looks pretty much like the Listing 6 on the following site which is using it:

[link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails06099/index.html)

And interestingly enough I do not get the error with the following line:

    `File.metaClass.isEmpty = { -> false }`

So, how would I unit test the action in Listing 6 of the above link?

Answer (score 0):

Does your test class inherit from `GroovyTestCase` or from `ControllerUnitTestCase`?
For integration tests it should be `GroovyTestCase`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That might have been the problem. I thought about that but because `ControllerUnitTestCase` is actually a subclass of `GroovyTestCase` I did not try it...

Comment: Oops. Was getting excited too early... it still did not work :-(

Answer (score 0):

True, I cannot find it in the javadocs either. Our action looks pretty much like the Listing 6 on the following site which is using it:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails06099/index.html

And interestingly enough I do not get the error with the following line:

```
File.metaClass.isEmpty = { -> false }
```